Convertir filas a columnas con PIVOT SQL
tengo la siguiente tabla en SQL



ID
Nombre paro
Tiempo




1344
Comida
00:05:00


1344
Ajuste
00:03:10


1344
Calidad
00:02:40


1346
Calidad
00:01:20


1346
Cambio modelo
00:06:40


1346
Ajuste
00:04:34


1347
Cambio modelo
00:05:54



Como pueden ver, no todos los ID tienen los mismos motivos, la mayoría puede ser diferente
y quisiera hacerle un reordenamiento a algo asi:



Id
Comida
Ajuste
Cambio modelo
Calidad
Produccion




1344
00:05:00
00:03:10
NULL
00:02:40
NULL


1346
00:05:00
00:03:10
00:06:40
00:04:34
NULL


1347
00:05:00
00:03:10
00:05:54
00:04:34
NULL



La tabla podria quedarse en NULL o en 00:00:00 eso me seria indiferente
El query que tengo ahorita para el sql es el siguiente:
select 
PM.nombreParo,
  CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, SUM(
    DATEPART(SECOND, TM.TiempoMuerto) + 

             60 * DATEPART(MINUTE, TM.TiempoMuerto) + 
             3600 * DATEPART(HOUR, TM.TiempoMuerto ) 
        ), 0) AS TIME) as TiempoMuerto,

TM.idCorrida from Produccion.TiemposMuertos TM   
left join Administracion.ParosXMaquina PM on TM.idParoXMaquina = PM.id
group by PM.nombreParo,TM.idCorrida
order by idCorrida desc

Tengo entendido que puedo utilizar una PIVOT para hacer el cambio, pero alguien me podria dar una orientada?
Gracias¡

Claro que se puede hacer con PIVOT. Sin embargo, siempre aconsejo un método llamado agregado condicional. Esta opción puede hacer lo mismo que PIVOT pero tiene más flexibilidad y en ciertos casos mejor rendimiento. El secreto para entenderlo es que dentro de una función de agregado puedes poner cualquier expresión y eso incluye el CASE.
Para evitar repetir la constante conversión a segundos, también incluí el comando APPLY para factorizar el código.
SELECT 
    --Nuestra forma de agrupar
    TM.idCorrida, 
    --Esto se repite y puedes copiar, pegar y modificar rápidamente el código
    CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, SUM( CASE WHEN PM.nombreParo = 'Comida'        THEN TMS.TiempoMuertoSegundos ELSE 0 END), 0) AS TIME) AS Comida, 
    CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, SUM( CASE WHEN PM.nombreParo = 'Ajuste'        THEN TMS.TiempoMuertoSegundos ELSE 0 END), 0) AS TIME) AS Ajuste,
    CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, SUM( CASE WHEN PM.nombreParo = 'Cambio modelo' THEN TMS.TiempoMuertoSegundos ELSE 0 END), 0) AS TIME) AS [Cambio modelo],
    CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, SUM( CASE WHEN PM.nombreParo = 'Calidad'       THEN TMS.TiempoMuertoSegundos ELSE 0 END), 0) AS TIME) AS Calidad,
    CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, SUM( CASE WHEN PM.nombreParo = 'Produccion'    THEN TMS.TiempoMuertoSegundos ELSE 0 END), 0) AS TIME) AS Produccion
FROM      Produccion.TiemposMuertos    AS TM   
LEFT JOIN Administracion.ParosXMaquina AS PM ON TM.idParoXMaquina = PM.id
CROSS APPLY( --Factorizamos la conversión de tiempo a segundos.
             SELECT  DATEPART(SECOND, TM.TiempoMuerto) 
                    + 60 * DATEPART(MINUTE, TM.TiempoMuerto) 
                    + 3600 * DATEPART(HOUR, TM.TiempoMuerto ) AS TiempoMuertoSegundos) AS TMS
GROUP BY TM.idCorrida
ORDER BY idCorrida;

Una opción distinta es hacer un preagregado y así el agregado condicional queda más sencillo.
WITH TiemposMuertosXParo AS(
    SELECT 
        TM.idCorrida,
        PM.nombreParo,
        CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, SUM( DATEPART(SECOND, TM.TiempoMuerto) 
                                + 60 * DATEPART(MINUTE, TM.TiempoMuerto) 
                                + 3600 * DATEPART(HOUR, TM.TiempoMuerto )), 0) AS TIME) as TiempoMuerto
    FROM      TiemposMuertos    AS TM   
    LEFT JOIN ParosXMaquina AS PM ON TM.idParoXMaquina = PM.id
    GROUP BY PM.nombreParo,TM.idCorrida
)
SELECT 
    idCorrida,
    MAX( CASE WHEN nombreParo = 'Comida'        THEN TiempoMuerto ELSE '00:00:00' END) AS Comida,
    MAX( CASE WHEN nombreParo = 'Ajuste'        THEN TiempoMuerto ELSE '00:00:00' END) AS Ajuste,
    MAX( CASE WHEN nombreParo = 'Cambio modelo' THEN TiempoMuerto ELSE '00:00:00' END) AS [Cambio modelo],
    MAX( CASE WHEN nombreParo = 'Calidad'       THEN TiempoMuerto ELSE '00:00:00' END) AS Calidad,
    MAX( CASE WHEN nombreParo = 'Produccion'    THEN TiempoMuerto ELSE '00:00:00' END) AS Produccion
FROM  TiemposMuertosXParo
GROUP BY idCorrida
ORDER BY idCorrida;


Encontre una solucion que me fue funcional
select  *
FROM
(select 
TM.idCorrida as idCorrida,
PM.nombreParo as nombreParo,
  CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, SUM(
    DATEPART(SECOND, TM.TiempoMuerto) + 
             60 * DATEPART(MINUTE, TM.TiempoMuerto) + 
             3600 * DATEPART(HOUR, TM.TiempoMuerto ) 
        ), 0) AS TIME) as TiempoMuerto
from Produccion.TiemposMuertos TM   
left join Administracion.ParosXMaquina PM on TM.idParoXMaquina = PM.id
group by PM.nombreParo,TM.idCorrida
) AS SourceTable PIVOT(MAX([TiempoMuerto]) FOR [nombreParo] IN([Cambio de modelo],
                                                         [Mantenimiento correctivo],
                                                         [Ajuste],
                                                         [Producción],
                                                         [Falla en herramentales],
                                                         [Mantenimiento programado],
                                                         [Limpieza de máquina],
                                                         [Falta de programa],
                                                         [Tintas],
                                                         [Calidad],
                                                         [Comida],
                                                         [Bloqueo],
                                                         [Motivo sin nombre],
                                                         [Montacargas],
                                                         [Delta fuera de especificaciones])) AS PivotTable
                                                         order by idCorrida DESC

Solo que los campos que no tienen tiempo me aparecen NULL, si alguien tiene alguna recomendacion para que salgan 00:00:00 seria bien recibida, gracias¡

¿COALESCE?
